# Can i put tooltip on crosshair movement in rgraph?

Tags: rgraph

I am using a line graph and vertical crosshair which moves on mouse move. Now as crosshair moves i get the (x,y) coordinates on each tickmarks.

Now my requirement is to add tooltip synched with crosshair or on crosshair to show (x, y) coordinate on that tooltip?

Answer (score 0):

There is no X coordinate when using the Line chart - for that you'll need the Scatter chart - and you can then use the Scatter chart crosshair properties which are documented here:

http://www.rgraph.net/scatter

Comment: can i get the x coordinate of vertical lines in grid

Comment: The grid coordinates aren't saved - so you'll need to change the RGraph,background.Draw() function in the RGraph.common.core.js file.